# Choosing test functions to satisfy certain mean value property

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $D$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $h:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth *nonzero* function on $D$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_DhdV=0 & & (*)
\end{align}
where $dV$ is the standard volume element of $D$. Assume that both 
\begin{align}
D^+=\left\{x\in D:h(x)>0\right\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad D^-=\left\{x\in D:h(x)<0\right\}
\end{align}
are nonempty. I wish to construct two non-negative smooth functions $\phi,\psi:D\to\mathbb{R}$ (*Edit*: I require both to be nonzero.) such that the following hold:

1. supp $\phi\subseteq D^+$ and supp $\psi\subseteq D^-$;
2. the mean value property
   \begin{align}
   \int_D(\phi+\psi)hdV=0
   \end{align}
   holds.

There are certainly standard test functions with compact support satisfying 1. However, I am not sure how to make them satisfying 2 as well. Intuitively this seems pretty obvious but I have trouble to write down a concrete and explicit proof. I believe (*) is needed but I am not sure how.

Any comment, hint or answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is stupid but what about $\phi=\psi=0$ ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Ah, sorry. I wish to have both test functions to be nontrivial. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ok so $h=h^+ - h^-$. What if you considered the continuous linear functional $F_{h^+}(g)= \int_{D^+} g h^+$, where $g \in C^{\infty}_0 (D^+)$? Maybe you can prove that there is a non trivial $g$ such that $F_{h^+}(g)=0$. The same with the negative part

Comment: @tommy1996q Sorry for not quite getting it. If such g exists, it must change sign in $D^+$ in order for $gh^+$ to change sign in $D^+$ as well. But then how do we modify this $g$ in order to get my $\phi$ which does not change sign in $D^+$? ($\phi$ is always nonnegative in $D^+$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to it. Choose $\phi_\pm\in C^\infty_c(D^\pm)$ with $\phi_\pm\ge0$ and $\phi_\pm\ne0$. Then $\int \phi_+h>0$ and $\int\phi_-h<0$, so $$\int(\alpha\phi_++\phi_-)h=0$$for a suitable constant $\alpha>0$

Comment: Thanks. I feel bad for not recalling such a standard trick.

Comment: @Hopfeccentric me too